# Using the URLconf defined in iblogs.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answer that solves my situation.

I'm looking at the Django tutorial, and I've set up the first URLs exactly as the tutorial has it, word for word, but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/, it gives me this error:
but when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ its working fine,where and what i am doing wrong?
i am using python version 3.11.1
please let me know for any other info

Page not found (404)

Request Method:

GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog

Using the URLconf defined in iblogs.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
```

```
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, blog, didn’t match any of these.
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from .views import home
urlpatterns = [
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path(' ', home)
              ]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello")

urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('blog/',include('blog.urls'))
              ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems:

1. There's a space in blog.urls for home, it should be `path('', home)`
2. http://127.0.0.1:8000/ isn't the blog app's root, http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ is

This is what you've currently got:

```py
# -> Actual Url

urlpatterns = [
  # -- main urls.py (on this indent level)

  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  # -> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/


  path('blog/', include('blog.urls')) 
  # Include Blog's Urls & prepend all with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/`   


    # -- blog/urls.py (on this indent level)

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # -> http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/admin/

    path(' ', home)
    # -> http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/{space}
    # note: space is invalid in URLs


]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Hopefully that's a good illustration

If you wanted http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to go to home you'd:

1. in the main urls.py change `path('blog/', include('blog.urls')` -> `path('', include('blog.urls')`
2. in blog.urls remove the space in home's url -> `path('', home)`

Comment: thanks for response my question,but its showing same results